# ssis ole db source cannot set output parameter of stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, ssis, dynamics-crm, oledb

I have stored procedure GET_RECORDS with output paremeter @RESULT.
I want to use this procedure in Ole Db Source component of my SSIS package.

I  had set sql query as "exec GET_RECORDS ? OUTPUT" and had set the params

[image]

But when I am trying to do preview - I am getting an error

[image]

What am I doing wrong? Do you have any ideas?

Thank you.
With regards, Yuriy.

Comment: Under Parameters try using "0" instead of "@RESULT"

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your code, nor should you change anything. The SSIS designer just doesn't allow you to set a parameter value when you click preview.

Comment: One more question - the variable, which I am passing to output parameter always returns without value (it is assigning inside of procedure) in SSIS. But, when I am running this procedure in sql studio directly - it successfully returns required output value.
What can be wrong here?